# Acces to component instance inside mat-row Angular Material Table

Tags: angular, angular-directive, mat-table

```html
 <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> <app-my-component [position]="element.position" ></app-my-component> </td>
  </ng-container>
```

[image of my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLigs.png)

Hello,
I want to access to my component instance that is inside a `matRow`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mmuf6a

I have create an row `directive` with host `on click` listener and I try to get the `component` inside my row with the `ng.probe` function

Is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to use @ViewChildren() decorator to get List of all your custom components placed inside the table component.

**table-basic-example.html**

```
<tr mat-row
    [cdkRowDirective]="row"
    *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;let i = index"
    (click)="doSomething(i)">
</tr>
```

**table-basic-example.ts**

```
export class TableBasicExample {
  @ViewChildren(MyComponent) private myComponents QueryList<MyComponent>;

  public doSomething(index: number): void {
    const item: MyComponent = this.myComponents.find((item: MyComponent, i: number) => {
      return index === i;
    });
    item.doWork();
  }
}
```

After that you could traverse through this list using `QueryList` api methods (map, find etc.).
Then add click event handler on row and pass row index to it, then access custom component by this index.

Comment: is there a solution where we can go through the directive (with a viewchild) for acces to the component ?

Comment: Yes, if I correctly understand, but in that case you should also store link to this component in this directive (probably using @Host() decorator in directive constructor or something similar).